# Determining spectrum of $A$ from values of $\text{tr}(A^k)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite $n\times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{R}$ with trace 1. I'm interested in understanding how $\lambda_k$, the $k$th largest eigenvalue, decays in magnitude with respect to $k$.

I'm able to estimate $\text{tr}(A^k)$ for $0<k<n$ . Are there any inequalities I can employ to use those estimates for an upper bound on $\lambda_k$? IE, perhaps an upper bound of the form

$$\lambda_k < \frac{C}{k^{p}}$$

In my application, it's been hypothesised (Section 3.5 of [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04164.pdf)) that $C=1$ and $p=1$

Comment: Your title and your question body are not quite aligned. If you know $\mathrm{tr}(A^k)$ for all $1\le k\le n$ then by the Newton-Girard identities you can exactly determine the spectrum of $A$ (as a complex spectrum)

Comment: In what sense do the eigenvalues of $A$ "decay", when $A$ is unchanging? I think we need some context

Comment: For a single large random matrix, we expect eigenvalues to decay because of Wigner-surmise kind of laws. IE, eq 11 and 12 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06740

Comment: @FShrike I found some pages on "Newton-Girard", but can't tell if it can be used in practice to get estimates of $\lambda_k$ (magnitude of $k$th largest eigenvalue)

Comment: I don’t know about estimation. The point was, if you know *precisely* the values of $\mathrm{tr}(A^k)$ for $1\le k\le n$ you can, in principle, precisely determine the spectrum of $A$. However there isn’t a neat closed form as far as I know - you have to step through a Newton-Girard algorithm. Maybe you could get some careful bounds this way, I don’t know. I don’t know about random matrices... I suggest you edit some more background into the post, anyway

Comment: If you have the actual matrix, why not use the standard techniques of numerical linear algebra to compute the eigenvalues, rather than limiting yourself to using $\text{tr}(A^k)$?

Comment: The matrix in question (Gauss-Newton of typical neural network objective) is too large to represent explicitly and we query it using matrix-vector products. Diagonal blocks can be written explicitly, but even those are too large for direct methods, here's an example -- https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41639/finding-spectrum-of-a-kronecker-factored-block-partitioned-matrix

Comment: The power method (for the largest eigenvalue) and deflation use matrix-vector products.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov [Here's the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) for the Newton Girard identities, in case that helps